# Onclick function doesnt work more than twice

Tags: javascript, tabs, onclick, accordion

I have a button that opens up the relevant accordion tab (TAB 2), when I first click the button it opens tab2, if I go back and click it a second time it works (goes to TAB2) BUT if i click it a third time nothing happens:

My button:

```
    <a onclick="changeTab2();">
```

My function:

```
<script>

var tabHeight = $('.tab.active').height();
function animateTabHeight() {
    tabHeight = $('.tab.active').height();
    $('.tabs-content').stop().css({
        height: '100' + '%'
    });
}


function changeTab2() {
    var getTabId = $('.tabs-header .active a').attr('tab-id');
    $('.tab').stop().fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }).hide();
    $('.tab[tab-id=' + 2 + ']').stop().fadeIn(300, function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        animateTabHeight();
    });
}

</script>
```

No idea to why it stops working.

Comment: How many tabs are there?

Comment: There are 3 tabs, but this button only opens tab-id-2

Comment: What error return console?

Comment: Also post HTML if you can.

Comment: Add your tab HTML as well, so that we can produce an isolated runnable code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Diego Cespedes  I get no error in my chrome console

Comment: I don't see the problem. I click on your buttons as many times as I want, they keep working.

Comment: click on GO TO TAB 2 - it doesnt work after to clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click event is binding only in the page load. That is why it is working in the first place. Try to dynamically bind click function each time the tab is opened.
Set id to a and bind click event.

```
    <a class="t1" id="subDiv1"></a>

    $('#subDiv1').unbind("click");
    $('#subDiv1').bind("click",function(){

       // place your code here

   });
```

Now call this inside the #tab-1 click function.